# Can not squeeze dim[1], expected a dimension of 1, got 14 [[{{node metrics_2/acc/Squeeze}}]]

Tags: tensorflow

I have written a code in python for image classification, but after writing code, I have got this error and in the dataset of images, there are images of sizes min. 655x53, my task is to classify the images of cells into 14 categories. there are total 6889 images of training set and 3771 images of test/validation set

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

train_dir = '/vista/train1'
validation_dir = '/vista/test1'

train_data = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1/255,
                            rotation_range = 20,
                            width_shift_range = 0.2,
                            height_shift_range = 0.2,
                            zoom_range = 0.2,
                            horizontal_flip = True,
                            fill_mode = 'nearest')

validation_data = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1/255)

train_gen = train_data.flow_from_directory(train_dir,
                                        batch_size = 30,
                                        class_mode = 'categorical',
                                        target_size = (400,200))

validation_gen = validation_data.flow_from_directory(validation_dir,
                                                 batch_size = 30,
                                                 class_mode = 
'categorical',
                                                 target_size = (400,200))

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64,(3,3),activation = 'relu',input_shape = 
(400,200,3)),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),

    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128,(3,3),activation = 'relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),

    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128,(3,3),activation = 'relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),

    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128,(3,3),activation = 'relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),

    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(256,activation = 'relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.20),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(14,activation = 'softmax')
    ])

model.compile(optimizer = 'Adam',
          loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
          metrics = ['acc'])

df = int(3711/30)
ef = int(6889/30)

history = model.fit_generator(train_gen,
                          steps_per_epoch = df,
                          epochs = 20,
                          validation_data = validation_gen,
          `enter code here`                validation_steps = ef,
                          verbose =2)

model.save_weights('/vista',overwrite=True,save_format = '.h5')
```

Comment: Please copy "error" on screen completely to make question understandable.

Comment: File "C:\Users\adity\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors_impl.py", line 528, in __exit__
    c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))

InvalidArgumentError: Can not squeeze dim[1], expected a dimension of 1, got 14
  [[{{node metrics/acc/Squeeze}}]]

Comment: as it was not accepting the whole error I skipped some of the error